# How to Deploy to Azure websites using Visual Studio Online and TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I have an MVC 5 application with Entity Framework. I was hoping to setup a continuous delivery using Visual Studio Online and TFS to Azure websites.
At first, it looked like i succeeded in setting up my application for continuous delivery, as when i check in the project, the build started and succeeded. Then i went to browse the website, there was nothing. I went into Visual Studio Online to check my builds, i noticed that under "Completed" tab, all builds completed successfully, but when i click on "Deployed" tab none were deployed "No builds have been deployed today by anyone"

I followed [Continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Online](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/) and i was under the impression that all i need is to check in my code and it would deploy to azure.

Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: What do you see at the end of the build log? Also can you confirm you've used the continuous deployment build template?

Comment: @RichardBanks i isolated the problem. It couldn't reference Nuget packages because i wasn't using the default folder, rather i created a lib folder and instructed my solution to use that.

Comment: Excellent :-) Can you post that as an answer and then mark it as an answer once you're able to.